# call function after function from setTimeout finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is function fadeItem() and will run after 1 second after DOM is loaded, now i want to call another function after fadeItem() finish.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navigation ui-slider-tabs-list">
   <li style="" class="effect selected hide_selected"> <a id="" href="#company-profile">
      Company Profile                                                </a>
   </li>
   <li style="" class="effect"> <a id="" href="#sg-corporate-value">
      SG Corporate Value                                                </a>
   </li>
   <li style="" class="effect"> <a id="" href="#sg-corporate-philosophy">
      SG Corporate Philosophy                                                 </a>
   </li>
   <li style="" class="effect"> <a id="" href="#sg-critical-success-factors">
      SG Critical Success Factors                                                 </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function fadeItem() {
        $('ul.navigation li:hidden:first').delay(100).fadeIn(fadeItem);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        // Do something after 1 second 
        fadeItem();     

    }, 1000);

    // try to run this after fadeItem() finish
    $('.ui-slider-tabs-list li.selected').removeClass('hide_selected');  <----

    $('ul.navigation li').hide();  

});
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.selected a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.hide_selected a {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

the problem is fadeItem() and removeClass() is run at the same time. I want to run fadeItem() first then removeClass().

So the result should be underline link for Company Profile after fadeItem() animation finish, not at the beginning.

You can check my fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/bpY6v/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in what you want to be out after the fadeout to the callback function as follows:

```
 function fadeItem() {
    $('ul.navigation li:hidden:first').delay(100).fadeIn(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hide_selected');
        fadeItem();
    });
}
```

If you need to remove the class after he displays all the elements, thus:

```
 function fadeItem() {
    if($('ul.navigation li:hidden').length>0){
        $('ul.navigation li:hidden:first').delay(100).fadeIn(function(){
            fadeItem();
        });
    } else {
        $('.ui-slider-tabs-list li.selected').removeClass('hide_selected');
    }
}
```

Comment: almost correct but i need to `removeClass` after fadeItem() done, i mean after `SG Critical Success Factors` loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Put the removeClass inside the setTimeout, right after fadeItem();